# Why can't I stop NSTimer?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have completely hit a wall. This should not be as difficult as it has been for me. I start my timer, no problem. When I try to stop it, it keeps going. I've tried invalidating in the usual way, but it is basically ignored for some reason. What am I doing wrong?!

Code:

```
var random = CGFloat()

var timer = NSTimer()

var counter = 0 as CGFloat

func startCountdown() {

    counter = 0

    random = CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX) * 5)

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func stopCountdown() {

    timer.invalidate()

}

@IBAction func startGame(sender: AnyObject) {

    startCountdown()

}

func updateCounter() {

    counter++

    println("counter: \(counter) random: \(random)")

}

@IBAction func tapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if counter >= random {

        println("Good job")

        stopCountdown()

        //startCountdown()


    } else {

        println("Game over")

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the problem, but you have two methods named `updateCounter()` and two methods named `startCountdown()` and two methods named `stopCountdown()` in your code.

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot.

Comment: Did not think that was allowed in swift?  He should be getting a compile error

Comment: I'm guessing it was just a cut-and-paste error, not the actual code.

Comment: Nope, I just pasted twice when posting the question.

Comment: When you try to stop it using `tapped`, do you get the `"Good job"` message or the `"Game over"` message?

Comment: Check your connections in the Storyboard to ensure that the button which triggers "tapped:" isn't connected with "startGame:" too

Comment: Thanks HorseT! That got it worked out!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an orphan `NSTimer` hanging around in memory. Because `NSTimer`s are scheduled on the run loop they aren't necessarily deallocated when you overwrite instance variables pointing to them.

What I expect is happening is that you are somehow scheduling the timer twice before the first invalidation happens. When you schedule a new timer in `startCountdown()` you overwrite the previous timer, but don't invalidate it. If you have somehow called `startCountdown()`/`startGame()` twice this means you have a still firing timer that your `stopCountdown` can't affect because the `timer` instance variable is now pointing at a different object.

If this is what's happening, the fix is easy - just invalidate the old timer in `startCountdown()` before scheduling the new one.

Comment: I think Rich is onto the right answer. When you declare the var you are instantiating an NSTimer and in startCountdown() you instantiate a NEW NSTimer and assign it to the var. If you invalidate the timer in startCountdown before you set it I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had my `startButton` starting an NSTimer while `tapped` started another timer at the same time. I just rearranged the app a little bit. I started the timer initially using `viewDidLoad()`.